# How can I test a button onClick which uses props.history for it's function in rtl?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

I'm using react testing library and I want to test a button which is :

```
<button data-testid="btn" onClick={() => props.history.push(`/post/${value}`)} > Search </button>
<input data-testid="input" type="text" value={value} onChange={(e) => handle(e.target.value)} />
```

and I test it's onClick function like this :

```
test('Button should navigate the url when enabled', () => {
        render(<Home />);
        const input = screen.getByTestId('input');
        const btn = screen.getByTestId('btn');
        fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: '12' } });
        fireEvent.click(btn);
    });
```

But it gives me an error :

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

      19 |                              <button
      20 |                                      data-testid="btn"
    > 21 |                                      onClick={() => props.history.push(`/post/${value}`)}
         |                                                                   ^
      22 |                                      disabled={!value}
      23 |                                      type="submit"
      24 |                              >
```

The app itself works fine when I npm start but fails only when testing it .
How can I solve this push of undefined ?

Comment: You don't seem to pass *any* props when rendering the component...

Comment: @jonrsharpe How can I define it in the test ?

Comment: The props? Same way you define them anywhere else `name={value}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass props to the rendered component, in this case - `<Home />`:

```
import history from 'history' // Or a file you made that contains an instance of history

test('Button should navigate the url when enabled', () => {
        render(<Home history={history} {...otherProps} />);
        const input = screen.getByTestId('input');
        const btn = screen.getByTestId('btn');
        fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: '12' } });
        fireEvent.click(btn);
    });
```

Comment: I did the exact thing and still throws the same error

Comment: Please check that the `history` you import is defined